# Rails 4: cannot install rubyzip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubyzip

I am trying to install `rubyzip` into my Rails 4 app, but I keep getting `cannot load such file` errors.  Here are the things I've tried:

1. A. Gemfile: `gem 'rubyzip'`
   B. `bundle install`
   C. ...Using rubyzip 1.1.4...
   D. In my controller: `require 'zip'`
   E. Error: `cannot load such file -- zip`
2. A. Gemfile: `gem 'rubyzip', "~> 0.9.9"`
   B. `bundle install`
   C. ...Installing rubyzip 0.9.9 (was 1.1.4)...
   D. In my controller: `require 'zip/zip'`
   E. Error: `cannot load such file -- zip/zip`

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Had to restart my server and then it worked.